# NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 not found on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I bought a laptop about 5 years ago running Ubuntu 18.04. It has these two chips:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 4GB GPU

Over the years I've updated to 20.04, and am now on 22.04. Somewhere along the line, the GPU seems to have disappeared from the system.When I run the below commands, I get nothing back about the NVIDIA GPU:

```
~$ lspci | grep -e VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
~$
```

Can someone please advise on how I can get the GPU recognized and used by the OS again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a hardware issue. When I boot connected to an external monitor with the laptop screen off, the GPU is not there. But if I boot with both screens on, it is there:

```
~$ lspci | grep -e VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```